# Query posts only shows 1

Tags: wp-query

I have an array of ids:

```
var_dump($userPostsInternal);
  -> string(13) "128537,128545"
```

Then I do

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array($userPostsInternal),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
    $title = $post->title;
    echo $title;
}
```

But I only get 1 title. There are 2 articles and they do have the ids we see in the `var_dump();`

I even tried:

```
foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo $title;
```

But I still get one title only.

If I explode `$userPostsInternal` I get `array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "128537" [1]=> string(6) "128545" }` and no results at all

Answer (score 1):

OK this is the thing:

I used a query

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array($userPostsInternal),
```

Taking the fact the following is a string

```
var_dump($userPostsInternal);
  -> string(13) "128537,128545"
```

I thought declaring the array here would work

```
array($userPostsInternal)
```

But it's not, therefore [thanks to a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57044052/1018804), suggesting me to explode `$userPostsInternal` converting the string into an array, I then had to remove the array declaration, making the query like:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $userPostsInternal,
```